# Automation Capybara extract value from checked radio button

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, automated-tests, capybara

I am looking for a way to check what radio is selected and save the value of that option into a variable. 
once i have the variable i want to build a switch statement which will give me the logic to decide what to do.

here is the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="option_1" name="registration[registrationType]" id="option_1_id" class="radio">
        (Option 1)
<input type="radio" value="option_2" name="registration[registrationType]" id="option_2_id" class="radio">
        (Option 2)
<input type="radio" value="option_3" name="registration[registrationType]" id="option_3_id" class="radio" checked="checked">
        (Option 3)
```

option 3 is the checked option (checked="checked")
I want to extract the value of option 3 (option_3) and save it in a variable

default_option = #the code that extracts the default option

```
case default_option
when "option_1"
  puts 'lets do something with this'
when "option_2"
 puts 'lets do something with this'
when "option_3"
 puts 'lets do something with this'
else
  puts 'cant do much with this'
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `find(:radio_button, 'option_3_id', checked: true).value' returns?

Comment: this returns the ID  which is exactly what i wanted. Thanks

Comment: i will add a more complete answer Andy

Comment: please accept it if it helped ;) and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case the 'option_3_id` is checked, you can find its value by

```
find(:radio_button, 'option_3_id', checked: true).value
```

But as you don't know which radio button is checked, you should first find all the options and verify which one is currently checked (`checked:true/false`), and then retrieve its value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the value of the checked radio in a group of them you want to use the shared name and the checked filter

```
find(:radio_button, 'registration[registrationType]', checked: true).value
```